# Debugging on iOS 14.1 using Xcode 11.3.1 with iOS 14.1 DeviceSupport folder installed not working

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, ios14, xcode11.3.1

I am getting an error when trying to debug iOS 14.1 iPhone using Xcode 11.3.1. It installs the app fine but doesn't debug. I get this error. Anybody able got this and able to resolve this?

**An error was encountered while attempting to communicate with this device. (The service is…**

*Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE8000022).*
[image]

Details of the error log is below:

An error was encountered while attempting to communicate with this device. (The service is invalid.)
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402653150
Failure Reason: Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE8000022).
User Info: {
DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
"com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000126ca76e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000126ca7de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000126cb8d0c __63-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startFirstServiceOf:unlockKeybag:]_block_invoke + 301
3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000126cb84db __48-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection futureWithSession:]_block_invoke_3 + 22
4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000126caa15f __DTDKExecuteInSession_block_invoke_2 + 35
5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000126ca9593 __DTDKExecuteWithConnection_block_invoke_2 + 473
6   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000126ca9391 __DTDKExecuteWithConnection_block_invoke + 106
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7302463d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff73030129 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
9   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010b1d8110 DVTDispatchBarrierSync + 208
10  DVTFoundation                       0x000000010b1af538 -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 64
11  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000126ca9292 DTDKExecuteWithConnection + 226
12  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000126ca9fc9 DTDKExecuteInSession + 376
13  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000126cb8410 __48-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection futureWithSession:]_block_invoke_2 + 112
14  DVTFoundation                       0x000000010b1d5e7a **DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK** + 7
15  DVTFoundation                       0x000000010b1d7552 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff730235f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7302463d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7302a8e0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 602
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7302b396 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 385
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff730336ed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff73264611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff732643fd start_wqthread + 13
);
}

Comment: I have the same issue and have tried all of the usual solutions including cleaning build folder, removing the app from the device, deleting Xcode's Derived Data folder, rebooting the device, rebooting the computer, reconnecting the device and doing all of those thing at once. The app installs successfully but when it tries to actually run it an connect to the running instance an error with the same error codes as yours appears. Trying some of the above may help you. It seems to have worked for many others.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. I usually just need to add DeviceSupport files but nothing is working with iOS 14.1 and Xcode 11.3.1. What's strange is it was working with iOS 14.0. I may just need to upgrade to Xcode 12, but that's a rather lengthy process for the project I'm working on.

Comment: Same issue. I try with all solutions that I solved this issue but now, with iOs 14.1 is impossible. I hope somebody can help us. The App installed on the device but debug is not running, xCode shows the error and communication to the device is off.

Comment: I ended up upgrading to Catalina and Xcode 12. I am able to debug now. Read somewhere that on iOS 14 devices the debugging uses a secure channel between the debugger and the phone. This is supported only in Xcode 12.